# Validate size of upload file in jquery

Tags: file-upload, validation

I wrote this code:
html:

```
   <input type="file" id="Gfile_1" class="upfile"/>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
$('.upfile').bind('change', function() {
var a=(this.files[0].size);
alert(a);
if(a > 80000);
{
    alert('large');
}

})

});
```

"alert(a)" show size of file correctly but if is always true.
why?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but if is always true. why?

Because you have a semicolon blocking the rest of the conditional...

```
if(a > 80000); // <- remove the semicolon
{
    alert('large');
}
```

Should be...

```
if(a > 80000) {
    alert('large');
}
```

Suggestion/Tip:  Using proper indentation and formatting will make these errors easier to spot.

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $('.upfile').bind('change', function() {
        var a=(this.files[0].size);
        alert(a);
        if(a > 80000) {
            alert('large');
        };
    });
});
```